# OOP PHP novice: how do I add a concatenate a string with each loop?

Tags: php, oop, loops, concatenation

Hi I'm an experienced PHP developer without any OOP skills and I'm looping round a result and need to concatenate a string like this:

```
while($row = $DB->fetchArray($homeResult))
    {
       $labelObject->getcustomerCycle($row['customer_uid'],$_REQUEST['start']); 
    }

//then output $labelObject.
```

So with each loop I need:

```
$labelObject += $labelObject->getcustomerCycle($row['customer_uid'],$_REQUEST['start']);
```

or something that does the same job :) Thanks!

Comment: Does $labelObject have a setCustomerCycle method? (Assuming customerCycle is the string you want to append to).

Comment: getcustomerCycle is a function which queries all the data I need and creates code ready to be output into a PDF format. so if I loop round and grab all the code for every customer, stick it in $labelObject and I'll then output it all at once.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you just need to store the results of all the calls. You can do this using a standard variable:

```
$string = '';
while($row = $DB->fetchArray($homeResult)){
       $string .= $labelObject->getcustomerCycle($row['customer_uid'],$_REQUEST['start']);
}
echo $string;
```